# How to aggregate values over time

Tags: c#

In my current project I have started to extend the logic with statistical data for better control, f.e.:

- Operations per hour / Averages per hour / response times

A first approach started with dedicated classes scattered over the application, now I am trying to find a more generic solution.
Requirements:

1. NET framework 4.6.1
2. Serialize / Deserialize with JSON.NET
3. aggregate over small time segments first (hours), later aggregate these per day with a max retention time

I guess this is a pretty common scenario , so I'd be grateful for ideas / comments / suggestions / links.
I also have the feeling I am reinventing the wheel, but a search in stackoverflow / google didnt reveil anything useful. Maybe I just used the wrong search terms.

**Edit:**
I realized that posting a draft code might sound like a request for a code review, which was not intended.
So I changed this to an open question.

I am mainly struggling with my 3rd requirement for a mechanism to condense statistical data, f.e. from minutes -> hours -> days.

Anybody got some ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask such a question. Maybe you should ask that on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Writing this post at least helped to understand the problem and why I am not too happy with this design: i.e. the aggregator class can only aggregate per single time segment only. That makes automatic aggregating from shorter cycles to longer cycles difficult

Comment: @Ackdari thx, I didn't even know [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) existed. But I'm not asking for a code review, I have the feeling the basic approach is flawed